# How can I tell log4net which appender to use from app.config

Tags: c#, logging, log4net, log4net-configuration

I had a quick log4net question. How can I specify which appender to use from the app.Config?
This particular config file references 2 different appenders. Both are rolling file appenders but they point to different files. Throughout the application log4net is being called and a type is passed into the constructor. like this...

```
 private static readonly ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Foo));
```

How does log4net know which appender to choose? Can you map types to specific named appenders? I know there are 5 constructors for GetLogger, can you pass a type and an appender name? I see "repositoryName", not sure what that is.  If anyone can point me in the right direction I would greatly appreciate it. I would like a certain set of types to log specifically to one appender.

Thanks for any tips,
~ck in San Diego

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a `<logger>` element, using the full class name of `Foo`:

```
<logger name="full.parent.namespace.Foo">
  <level value="WARN" />
  <appender-ref ref="SomeAppender" />
</logger>
```

Specify a minimum level and reference to the required output appender to use.

You can also use a single `<logger>` for all classes in a particular namespace by omitting the class name.

```
<logger name="full.parent.namespace">
  ....
</logger>
```