# log4net filter doesnt work

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I'm using log4net and I am trying to use a filter so that only one appender can write to a specific file.

Can anyone tell me why this isn't working? I would like only the appender called "ErrorLogFileAppender" to write into the file..

```
<appender name="ErrorLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <file value="..\\WebErrors.log" />
   <appendToFile value="true" />
   <rollingStyle value="Size" />
   <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
   <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
   <staticLogFileName value="true" />
   <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
   <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %logger{1} %m%n" />
   </layout>

   <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
     <!-- allows this sub-namespace to be logged... -->
     <loggerToMatch value="ErrorLogFileAppender" />
   </filter>

</appender>
```

This is how I get the logger that should be able to write to the file:

```
private static ILog _fileLogger = LogManager.GetLogger("ErrorLogFileAppender");
```

But this logger (used in another class) can also write to the same file, which is wrong:

```
private static ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

Comment: FWIW, I think you're deviating from the way log4net is designed to work with this approach - your code shouldn't know that it's logging to an `ErrorLogFileAppender`, it should just log at the right level - worry about what and where is actually being logged in your config.

Comment: Good thought. Will look at some changes. But my problem with the filter is still there though

Comment: Oh yes, you'll still need the filters etc to work in some fashion if you want to just log errors from a particular component.  Or set up only that logger to use that appender...

Comment: Please check this answer as well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3685965/how-can-i-tell-log4net-which-appender-to-use-from-app-config

Comment: And you have no clue why my filter isnt working.. :)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html#filters):

> Filters form a chain that the event has to pass through. Any filter along the way can accept the event and stop processing, deny the event and stop processing, or allow the event on to the next filter. **If the event gets to the end of the filter chain without being denied it is implicitly accepted and will be logged.**

(emphasis mine)

Since you don't have a filter in place to deny anything that *isn't* an `ErrorLogFileAppender`, everything will be logged still.  You can fix this by including a `DenyAllFilter`:

```
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
  <!-- allows this sub-namespace to be logged... -->
  <loggerToMatch value="ErrorLogFileAppender" />
</filter>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

---

Alternatively, you can configure log4net so that *only* that logger uses that appender, eg:

```
<logger name="ErrorLogFileAppender">
    <appender-ref ref="ErrorLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
```